# Search db using data obtained from json data

Tags: jquery

How can I search a db using data obtained from parsing json data?

```
function on_jsondata(data) {            
    var docs = data.response.docs;
    var searchText = data.response.docs[0].title;  //search term
    if(searchText) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'db.php',
            dataType: 'POST',
            data: {'text': searchText},
            success: function(html) {
                $("#result").show();
                $('#result').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: did u get any error ?

Comment: I didnt not get any result

Comment: data: {'text': searchText}, should be data: {text: searchText},

Comment: dataType: 'POST', this is wrong type should be post,dataType should be json

Comment: should be `type: 'POST'` and not `dataType` which is used for the expected response type from the server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function on_jsondata(data) {            
        var docs = data.response.docs;
        var searchText = data.response.docs[0].title;  //search term
        if(searchText) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'db.php',
                type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                data: {text: searchText},
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result").show();
                    $('#result').append(html);
                }
            });
    }
 }
```